# What is the best way to sort a roughly ordered stream?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, apache-kafka

I hava a kafka topic `unsorted`, whose keys are timestamps. The timestamps are roughly ordered and I want them to be completely ordered in near realtime. Currently I used a heap to buffer up to 10 thousand messages and send out half of the ordered messages to topic `sorted`. Is there a better way to do this?

'roughly ordered' means that messages are produced with current time(which is the key), but the network delay(+-1 second) makes messages arrive slightly unordered. The biggest time difference of two messages is 2 seconds. About 5k messages are produced per second.

Comment: Without any knowlage what 'roughly ordered' means in detail, it's impossible to ensure a sorted output without buffering all the data first and than sort it.

Comment: 'roughly ordered' means that messages are produced with current time(which is the key), but the network delay(+-1 second) makes messages arrive slightly unordered. The biggest time difference of two messages is 2 seconds. About 5k messages are produced per second.

Comment: Do they need be correct down to second, 1/10 second, ms, us or what are the requirements?

Comment: They need to be accurate as nanoseconds

Answer (score 1):

I would create a cache (array) big enough for the maximum number of package that we expect in 2s (because +/- 1s delay must be handled)
For arriving packages perform insert ( **O(log n)** )

And remove old messages (more than 2s older than newest) and send them to the output.

---

**optional extra optimization:**
To avoid copying while removing 'old' messages from the cache, you can organize the array as a zyclic-array (like a ring-buffer)

Comment: Insertion sort over ring buffer? Great idea. But the problem is that it can't handle traffic burst unless I choose a big enough ring buffer.

Comment: @Jack Hack: If you cannot guarantee an upper-bound for the size (or it is too big, to always use that much memory), you could go for a ring-buffer structured like a linked-list of arrays. That would slow down searching a bit (by number of linked-list-elements), but would allow handling bursts. Adding removing an array (on demand / no longer demanded) makes the structure a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented something similar myself.

I had two mechanisms:

1. Time-based:

- Keep a 'lastFlush' timestamp of the last time messages were sent out.
- Add new messages to an internal buffer
- After each poll, if the lastFlush timestamp is more than 2s olds, send out all messages that are older than 2s, in order, and update the lastFlush timestamp.

2. Buffer-size based:

- After each poll, if the buffer is full, send out the oldest half of the buffer, regardless of their age.

The 2nd mechanism will possibly still cause out-of-order messages is the buffer is not large enough, so that should be the exception.

BTW, we did consumer polling with a timeout of 100ms, to ensure we continued flushing the buffers, even when no new messages arrived.

An additional issue with keeping the buffer in memory, is how to ensure not loosing messages when processors go down.

We solved this using manual commits, to only commit incoming messages after they were flushed. This ensured that when one consumer was killed, the messages in the buffer were automatically replayed on the consumer that took over the partition. But that was very complicated to manage since when the messages were out-of-order, we had to sometimes keep older offsets while newer messages were already flushed. And we had to keep track of different offsets per kafka partition.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume your timestamps are only 1/1000s accurate, there are only 2000 different timestamps within the 2s interval.

So you could simply create 2000 lists of messages referring to each timestamp.

Insertion would be **O(1)** (append to the corresponding list)

Don't forget to write the old entries to your output. To avoid confusion, simply store one timestamp for each list to detect if it is >2s old and needs to be written to output.

---

If your timestamps are more accurate, you could go for more lists or internally sort the list for more precision